# Read the S3 file of format parqueet and convert the stream to java object

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm working on a Java project where I need to read data from a file stored in Parquet format and then convert this data into Java objects. Currently, I'm attempting to retrieve the Parquet file from an AWS S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for Java. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
String bucketName = "temp";
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, "recommendations.parquet"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS for Java V1 or [Java SDK V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html), you can read an object located in a S3 bucket and get the byte[] that represents the object.

NOTE - Java V1 is on path to deprecation and its use is not encouraged. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/.

**USING  V1**

If you really need to use AWS SDK for Java V1 (its strongly recommended that you upgrade to V2), here is solution to get byte[].

```
try {
            S3Object o = s3.getObject(bucket_name, key_name);
            S3ObjectInputStream s3is = o.getObjectContent();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(key_name));
            byte[] read_buf = new byte[1024];
            int read_len = 0;
            while ((read_len = s3is.read(read_buf)) > 0) {
                fos.write(read_buf, 0, read_len);
            }
            s3is.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

**USING V2**

Once you get the byte[], you can use that byte[] to meet your business requirements.

To get data from an S3 object, use this V2 code:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development
 * environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String usage = """

                Usage:
                    <bucketName> <keyName> <path>

                Where:
                    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name.\s
                    keyName - The key name.\s
                    path - The path where the file is written to.\s
                """;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        String path = args[2];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getObjectBytes(s3, bucketName, keyName, path);
    }

    public static void getObjectBytes(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path) {
        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key(keyName)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file.
            File myFile = new File(path);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```